# CORS error preflight missing allow origin header - axios -vue.js

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am working with vue and axios.
In one part of my project i am able to do post requests:

```
await axios.post(http://127.0.0.1:7000/favorite',body)
     .then((response)=>
    {
        console.log(response.data)

    }
    )
        .catch((error) => 
        {
            console.error(error)
        })
```

But in another part in another file i am getting CORS error.
The code is almost the same:

```
await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:7000/movie',body)
    .then((response)=>
    {
          console.log("update ok")
    }
    ).catch((error) => 
    {

          console.error(error)
    })
```

and i see in my api terminal an OPTIONS request
The CORS settings in my api are right:

```
CORS_ORIFN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Also i can do successful post requests from postman.
I tried everything, what could be wrong?

Comment: `CORS_ORIFN_ALLOW_ALL = True` does not look right at all...

Comment: so, any suggestions?(CORS_ORIFN_ALLOW_ALL = True is only for dev mode)

Comment: I do not have any suggestion. I even don't know what backend you are using! Im just pointing out `CORS_ORIFN_ALLOW_ALL` looks very strange ...I would expect something like `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL` instead...